# Android Rectangle Area Detection

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible in the Android framework to detect rectangle regions within an image or not ?

[image]

dimensions for the rectangle regions in the whole single image are not fixed.What i want is to detect all those regions crop them and display them separately

Answer (score 0):

You can get the drawing rectangle of a View like this:

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
mView.getDrawingRect(rect);
```

This will give you a rectangle containing the coordinates of where on the screen the View is drawn.

To get the left and top coordinates of the View on screen:

```
float viewLeftXCoord = rect.left; 
float viewTopXCoord = rect.top;
```

Comment: thanks for your response but how do we get to know from where rectangle area starts?

Comment: Updated my answer... Not sure if that helps :)